# is it possible to start a thread by calling run() inside a run()method?

Tags: java, multithreading

I know that run method should not be called to start a new thread execution, but i was referring [this article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html) where they have called `runnable.run();` inside another run method and it seems to be implying that it starts a new thread or its not at all ***creating*** threads, it just creates a new thread and runs all runnable in the same thread i.e task by task?

here is the code that article refers about.

```
 public class ThreadPool {

    private BlockingQueue taskQueue = null;
    private List<PoolThread> threads = new ArrayList<PoolThread>();
    private boolean isStopped = false;

    public ThreadPool(int noOfThreads, int maxNoOfTasks){
        taskQueue = new BlockingQueue(maxNoOfTasks);

        for(int i=0; i<noOfThreads; i++){
            threads.add(new PoolThread(taskQueue));
        }
        for(PoolThread thread : threads){
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void  execute(Runnable task) throws Exception{
        if(this.isStopped) throw
            new IllegalStateException("ThreadPool is stopped");

        this.taskQueue.enqueue(task);
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        this.isStopped = true;
        for(PoolThread thread : threads){
           thread.doStop();
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public class PoolThread extends Thread {

    private BlockingQueue taskQueue = null;
    private boolean       isStopped = false;

    public PoolThread(BlockingQueue queue){
        taskQueue = queue;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(!isStopped()){
            try{
                Runnable runnable = (Runnable) taskQueue.dequeue();
                runnable.run();
            } catch(Exception e){
                //log or otherwise report exception,
                //but keep pool thread alive.
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void doStop(){
        isStopped = true;
        this.interrupt(); //break pool thread out of dequeue() call.
    }

    public synchronized boolean isStopped(){
        return isStopped;
    }
}
```

questions:

1. Why **thread.start();** is called inside constructor?
2. How do i enque my task if **thread.start();** is called even before
   calling  **this.taskQueue.enqueue(task);**
3. To understand all these please post a driver class for this example
   with *maxNoOfTasks=10* and *noOfThreads=3*.and output for
           the same would be much appreciated.
4. Does Runnable.run() inside run method start a new thread ?

thanks

Comment: The `run` method is just an ordinary method, nothing special about it. The `Thread#start` method starts a thread. And after that it calls `run`. But `run` itself only executes the method, has nothing to do with threads in the first place. A `Runnable` is not a thread, it's just something which has a method called `run`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> i was referring this article where they have called `runnable.run()`; inside another run method and it seems to be implying that it starts a new thread.

Looking at the code, I don't see that implication at all.

It's not starting a new thread. It's running the next `Runnable` from a queue on the current pool thread.

> I know that run method should not be called to start a new thread execution...

Not *should not*, **cannot**. :-) Calling `run` just calls `run`, on the current thread, just like any other method call.

> 1. Why `thread.start();` is called inside constructor?

To start the thread that was just created with `new PoolThread(taskQueue)`.

> 2. How do i enque my task if `thread.start();` is called even before calling `this.taskQueue.enqueue(task);`

You pass it into `execute`. It gets added to the queue of things to do (`taskQueue`). One of the `PoolThread`s that `ThreadPool` created will pick it up when it's next free.

> 3. To understand all these please post a driver class for this example with maxNoOfTasks=10 and noOfThreads=3.and output for the same would be much appreciated.

I don't know what you mean by a driver class, but I think answering the questions is sufficient.

> 4. Does `Runnable.run()` inside run method start a new thread ?

No.

---

So to understand what this does, say you create a `ThreadPool` with 5 threads. The `ThreadPool` constructor creates and starts five `PoolThread` threads immediately. Those threads constantly check `taskQueue` to see if there's anything to do and, if so, they do it.

Initially, of course, `taskQueue` is always empty so the threads are busy-waiting, constantly spinning checking for something in `taskQueue`. (This isn't really ideal, it burns CPU for no good reason. It would be better to suspend threads when there's nothing to do, but that's starting to get pretty far from the actual question.)

Then, at some point, you call `execute` and pass in a task. That adds it to the `taskQueue`. The next time one of the five threads checks for something in `taskQueue`, it finds it, and runs it *on that thread* (not a new one).

Comment: please can you post a driver class wich can procude some outputs to better understand this?

Comment: You could explain the concept of a thread pool which OP seems to not be familiar with.

Answer (score 3):

**4. Does Runnable.run() inside run method start a new thread ?**

No, it will not start a new thread, It is not possible to start a new thread by calling run() method because JVM will not create a new thread until you call the start method.

If you call the run() method directly than it will be called on the same thread. JVM will not create separate thread for execution, it will execute on same thread.

On any thread instance if you call start() method it will create a new thread but if you call start() method second time on same instance, it will throw java.lang.IllegalStateException, because the thread is already started and you cannot restart it again.

You can only pause a thread in Java. Once it died it's gone.

I think this could be the reason to call like this.

```
Runnable runnable = (Runnable) taskQueue.dequeue();
runnable.run();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why thread.start(); is called inside constructor?

starts the threads in pool constructor.

the threads are already running.

```
Runnable runnable = (Runnable) taskQueue.dequeue();
```

blocks the running threads

taskQueue.enque() puts new object of type Runnable to the queue and any blocked thread takes this Runnable and executes it. All the threads are started when the pool is created and in those threads are Runnable simply executed.